# Is it possible to require confirmation before delete with Timeshift?

Tags: backup, system

Whilst trying out Timeshift in a new install, I accidentally clicked the delete button and Timeshift deleted my snapshot without requiring confirmation.

Is it possible configure Timeshift to insist on a confirmation before delete?

Also when I deleted (not using Timeshift) some snapshots written to a different partition, I think the disk space was not freed up afterwards, until I reformatted that partition? Not sure about this as I was just trying a few things out before committing, but Timeshift and GParted I think both reported significant used space still, even though the snapshots were gone/inaccessible.